# Angular :: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bookingHistoryListDO')

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a array type of Booking class in BookingHistoryList.ts,
When I am trying to submit the data to my backend it showing as described in below screenshot link.
In CreateUser.ts I have generated the Object for BookingHistoryList but in BookingHistoryList.ts how can I generate the object of Booking.ts which I am using as data structure for BookingHistoryListDO.

CreateUser.ts

```
import { Booking } from "./Booking";
import { BookingHistoryList } from "./BookingHistoryList";
import { LoginUser } from "./LoginUser";

export class CreateUser {
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string;
    birthdayDate!: string;
    gender!:  string;
    country!: string;
    phoneNumber!: string;
    loginDO !: LoginUser;
    bookingHistoryList !: BookingHistoryList;
    constructor() { 
        this.loginDO = new LoginUser();
        this.bookingHistoryList = new BookingHistoryList();
    }
}
```

BookingHistoryList.ts

```
import { Booking } from "./Booking";

export class BookingHistoryList {
    bookingHistoryListDO : Booking[];
}
```

Booking.ts

```
export class Booking {
    fromCity: string;
    toCity: string;
    date: string;
}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from 'src/app/service/location.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { CreateUserService } from 'src/app/service/create-user.service';
import { CreateUser } from 'src/app/CreateUser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  //Variables to be used in the html file
  currentUser : CreateUser;
  stringifiedData: string[] = [];
  Location: any;
  booking = {
    fromCity !: "",
    toCity !: "",
    date !: ""
  }

  fetchLocation()
  {
    this.GetRequest.fetchLocation().subscribe(data => {
      this.Location = data;
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.Location).length; i++)
      {
        this.stringifiedData.push(this.Location[i].locationName);
      }
    });
  }
  getBookingFormData()
  {
    if (this.validateForm())
    {
      this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      if (this.currentUser == null)
      {
        alert("Please login to book a trip");
        this.appRoutingModule.redirectToLogin();

      }
      else
      {
        this.currentUser.bookingHistoryList.bookingHistoryListDO.push(this.booking);
        console.log(this.currentUser);
        this.postRequest.sendUserData(this.currentUser);
      }
    }
  }
  validateForm()
  {
    if (this.booking.fromCity == "" || this.booking.toCity == "" || this.booking.date == "")
    {
      alert("Please fill in all the fields");
      return false;
    }
    else if (this.booking.fromCity == this.booking.toCity)
    {
      alert("Please select different destinations");
      return false;
    }
    else if (this.booking.date < new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])
    {
      alert("Please select a future date");
      return false;
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log(this.booking);
      return true;
    }
  }

  constructor(private GetRequest : LocationService, private postRequest : CreateUserService, private appRoutingModule : AppRoutingModule) { 
    try {

      this.fetchLocation();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error");
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

I have also tried the below format for BookingHistoryList.ts but showing same error

```
import { Booking } from "./Booking";

export class BookingHistoryList {
    bookingHistoryListDO : Array<{
        fromCity: string;
        toCity: string;
        date: string;
    }>;
}
```

Link to error:
[Error shown in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64uJg.png)

Comment: You declare `bookingHistoryListDO : Booking[]` but you never instantiate  it.  Try `bookingHistoryListDO  = Booking[]`

Comment: @E.Maggini I tried that but in square parathesis it shows error(An element access expression should take an argument.).

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: Your code shows this `stringifiedData: string[] = [];` so try that pattern.  `bookingHistoryListDO : Booking[] = []`